# Use a C++ function as an argument for another C++ function called by an exported Rcpp function

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I saw that it is possible to pass an *R* function as argument into *C++* using Rcpp. For example, you can do:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat example_cpp_func(Rcpp::Function my_r_func, arma::mat a){
  return Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(my_r_func(a));
}
```

That is fine but I'm searching for something slightly different.

Let be the following functions:

```
arma::mat f1(arma::mat& a){
  return a;
}

arma::mat func_2(Rcpp::Function g, arma::mat a){
  return Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(g(a));
}
```

I want to call `func_2` in a third function using `func_1` as argument. Is that possible? For example, I'm seeking to do:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat func_3(arma::mat a){
  return func_2(func_1, a);
             ## ^^^^ Pass a C++ function as a parameter
}
```

This is possible with R, but when I tried with Rcpp/RcppArmadillo I get the following error:

> could not convert ‘f1’ from ‘arma::mat (*)(arma::mat&)’ {aka ‘arma::Mat (*)(arma::Mat&)’} to ‘Rcpp::Function’ {aka ‘Rcpp::Function_Impl’}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example using the approach Ralf wrote in #1.  You can use pure C/C++ function pointers here, although you can do more complex things with C++11.

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

typedef arma::mat (*functype)(arma::mat&);

arma::mat f1(arma::mat& a){
  return a+1;
}

arma::mat f2(functype g, arma::mat a){
  return g(a);
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat f3(arma::mat a){
  return f2(f1, a);
}
```

R side:

```
> f3(matrix(1))
     [,1]
[1,]    2
```

Comment: Good reference cheatsheet for function pointers: https://f**kingfunctionpointers.com/.  Not sure if swearing is allowed, but the URL has the f word in it :O

Answer (score 2):

The error message says all there is: To C++ `f1` is a function that expects an `arma::mat`  as argument and returns an `arma::mat`. This is quite different from an `Rcpp::Function`, which is a thin wrapper around a R function. I see three possibilities:

1. Write an alternative `f2` function which expects a function pointer or `std::function` (requires C++11) with appropriate arguments.
2. Add an argument of type `Rcpp::Function` to `f3` which is used in the call to `f2`.
3. Get an appropriate R function with `Rcpp::Environment` and `Rcpp:Function`.

Without further information about the use case it is difficult to offer more advice.